# Python - Calculating the second column from the first one in a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

I am a beginner in Python and cannot cope with one of the moments of my project, so I would be glad you to help me:)

Lets's imagine, I have a *.txt file with only one column which looks like:

```
         Column-1

row-1    0
row-2    25.00
row-3    27.14
row-4    29.29
row-5    31.43
row-6    33.57
```

*Column with rows is added here just to simplify the explanation.

I need to calculate the second column which takes as input data from the Column-1 and outputs the result of subtraction of this row value from the previous one (if the row-1(Column-1) value is 0, than it should be 0 in the row-1(Column-2) as well). It should be like:

- row-2(Column-2) = row-2(Column-1) - row-1(Column-1)
- row-3(Column-2) = row-3(Column-1) - row-2(Column-1) and so on.

Let me show you how the output file shoud be like:

```
         Column-1  Column-2

row-1    0         0
row-2    25.00     25.00
row-3    27.14     2.14
row-4    29.29     2.15
row-5    31.50     2.21
row-6    33.57     2.07
```

For now I am only here with my programming:

```
import sys

with open('file.txt', "r") as f:
    sys.stdout = open('%s (calc).txt' % f.name, 'a')
    for line in f:
        column = line.strip().split()
        Column_1 = float(column[0])
        column.extend([None])
```

I wonder what to do next. Maybe, numpy is right for this task? I am not strong in it (basically, I don't know it at all), should I learn it?

Anyway, I would be really thankful for you contribution.

Comment: Take a look at Pandas' rolling_apply: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this would do what you asked:

```
INPUT = 'file.txt'
OUTPUT = 'calc.txt'

def main():
    with open(INPUT, 'r') as reader, open(OUTPUT, 'a') as writer:
        last_value = 0
        for line in reader:
            column_1, *remaining_columns = map(float, line.split())
            column_2 = column_1 - last_value
            last_value = column_1
            print(column_1, column_2, sep='\t', file=writer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You can simplify line 8 using `column_1 = next(map(float, line.split()))`

Comment: That is true, but the way it is written forces type checking on the rest of the columns. Taking you approach, it would be better to write `column_1 = float(next(iter(line.split())))` since map would not be needed. As line 8 currently stands, all columns will be checked to be valid float values.

Comment: Fair enough. But OP uses `float(line.split()[0])` which gives no indication of the type contained in others columns (if any). Maybe enforcing it to be float everywhere won't do it with their inputs.

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a quick response, it really works:) Though, it is a little bit difficult for me to understand all the process, I will try to.
Anyway, it works - thank you one more time)

Comment: Therefore, writing `column_1 = float(line.split()[0])` may have been best. My example is meant to show some possibilities that may be unknown. It will also spectacularly fail if the code and data do not meet the same expectations.

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be the following: Say you have two lists:

```
a = [1,2,3,0]
b = [0,1,2,3]
```

You can then subtract one list from the other using the following step:

```
import operator
map(operator.sub, a, b)
```

To do this, you'd need to read in your file as an array (using `array.append(value)` to get all the data in.

Then make a copy of your data, and offset it by one (the list length needs to be the same). How you handle the beginning and end of the array depends on how important these values are to you (maybe you can afford lose one value).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using list comprehensions and a zip:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

with open('file.txt', "r") as f:

    # read column one into a list
    column_1 = [float(line.strip()) for line in f]
    # compute differences of neighbouring values
    column_2 = [now - last for now, last in zip(column_1, [0.0]+column_1[:-1])]

    with open("result.txt", "w") as outfile:
        for c1, c2 in zip(column_1, column_2):
            print("{:.2f}\t{:.2f}".format(c1, c2), file=outfile)
```

What's happening here is we first create a list of all entries from the input file. By using zip we can create tuples from two (or more) iterables. We have to create a second list with the values shifted by 1 and adding a 0.0 at the front to act as a sentinel for the first entry.

Now we can zip these two lists together and compute the differences between the value pairs using the second list comprehension.

Learning numpy is always a good idea, but I think it would be overkill for this task.

Comment: **m00am**, thank you, I will try this.
As for the numpy - thanks for the advise, will do it later after being a little bit more confident in 'common' things:)